# Prove continuity with given condition

Tags: calculus

> Suppose the function $f$ has the property that
>   $$|f(x)-f(t)|\leq|x-t|$$
>   for each pair of points $(x,t)$ in the interval
>   $(a,b)$. Prove that $f$ is continuous on $(a,b)$

I tried to divide both sides by $|x-t|$, obtaining $$\frac {|f(x)-f(t)|}{|x-t|}\leq1$$

Then I have no idea how to choose
the $\epsilon$ to complete the proof
with the definition of continuity.

Thanks for answering.

Comment: You don't need to choose $\epsilon$. For a given positive $\epsilon$ you need to choose $\delta$. Well, let $t\in (a,b)$. For each $x\in (a,b)$ we have $|f(x)-f(t)|\leq |x-t|$. So what $\delta$ can we choose for $|x-t|<\delta$ to imply $|f(x)-f(t)|<\epsilon$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: A special case of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lipschitz_continuity.

Answer (score 1):

For each $\varepsilon>0$, take $\delta=\varepsilon$. Then$$\lvert x-y\rvert<\delta\iff\lvert x-y\rvert<\varepsilon\implies\bigl\lvert f(x)-f(y)\bigr\rvert<\varepsilon,$$since $\bigl\lvert f(x)-f(y)\bigr\rvert\leqslant\lvert x-y\rvert$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a variable $h$.

Let’s take a point $c$ in the given interval. We have 
$$0 \leq |f(c+h) - f(c)| \leq |c+h-c| =|h|$$ and

$$0 \leq |f(c)-f(c-h)| \leq |c-c+h| = |h|$$

No matter how small we make $h$ this is true, so if $h \rightarrow 0$ $$|f(c+h)-f(c)| = |f(c)-f(c-h)| = 0$$ so the function is continuous.